How to change the background color of a div when I click on it
I want to change the background color of a div when I click on it using only css not JavaScript. So when I click on it it should turn red. How do I do that using css?

Sounds like an X Y problem, why can't you use javascript? to do this with pure css will require the whole div to be nested within another element that has a click state. You could use <a></a> but that doesn't have a click state, just a visited state. If javascript is not allowed, I can only image what other things you are going to ask for next.

Why not try adding  role:button to the div and  then use active in css. You Can also use a tag and style it like div

You could use a checkbox inside that div to handle the click state and use :has() pseudo-class to change the style of the div.


div {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: blue;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

div:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
  background: red;
}
<div>
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
</div>



However, right now, the support for :has() is only at 92.79%. So alternatively, the checkbox could be before the div and use a position absolute to cover the div. Then you can to the same thing with the sibling selector:


.wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: blue;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .box {
  background: red;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>



